# Combining two T-SQL pivot queries in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Suppose you had this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Records
(
    RecordId       int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CreateDate     datetime          NOT NULL,
    IsSpecial      bit               NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_Records   PRIMARY KEY(RecordId)
)
```

Now a report needs to be created where the total records and the total special records are broken down by month.  I can use these two queries separately:

```
--      TOTAL RECORDS PER MONTH
SELECT January, February, March, April, May, June,
    July, August, September, October, November, December
FROM (
    SELECT RecordId, DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate) AS RecordMonth
    FROM dbo.Records
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    COUNT(RecordId) FOR RecordMonth IN (January, February, March, April, May, June,
    July, August, September, October, November, December)
) AS PivotTable;

--      TOTAL SPECIAL RECORDS PER MONTH
SELECT January, February, March, April, May, June,
    July, August, September, October, November, December
FROM (
    SELECT RecordId, DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate) AS RecordMonth
    FROM dbo.Records
    WHERE IsSpecial = 1
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    COUNT(RecordId) FOR RecordMonth IN (January, February, March, April, May, June,
    July, August, September, October, November, December)
) AS PivotTable;
```

The results might look like this:

```
                  Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec
total              0     0    2     2     1      0     0    1      2     1     2    4
total special      0     0    1     0     1      0     0    0      0     0     0    2
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries into a single more efficient query?

Comment: Combine how? Can you give a result set example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT
     CASE SQ.total_type
          WHEN 1 THEN 'total special'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'total expensive'
          ELSE 'total'
     END AS total_type,
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(R.CreateDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS January,
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(R.CreateDate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS February,
     SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(R.CreateDate) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS March,
     ...
FROM
     dbo.Records R
INNER JOIN
     (
          SELECT 0 AS total_type UNION ALL   -- All
          SELECT 1 UNION ALL                 -- IsSpecial
          SELECT 2                           -- IsExpensive
     ) AS SQ ON
     (R.IsSpecial | (R.IsExpensive * 2)) & SQ.total_type = SQ.total_type
GROUP BY
     SQ.total_type
ORDER BY
     SQ.total_type DESC
```

Comment: Tom, your answer was very helpful, but I'm struggling to extend this solution to include a third aggregation on the same query.  For example, if you had another field such as IsExpensive and you wanted the totals per month on a third result row.  How would you handle this third join?

Comment: You could change the subquery table to be a set of bitmaps for each of the different rows, which each bit being for one of the criteria. I'm about done for the day, but if I think of it I'll try to add an example.

Comment: I just changed the SQL code to more easily handle additional criteria. If you get another one, just add it in as the next power of 2 (so, "IsCheap" could be 4). Put it in the subquery, the case statement, and the join criteria and you should be good to go. You can also change around the values if you want to change the ordering of the results. It doesn't matter which is 1, 2, or 4 as long as they are consistent throughout the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one aggregate (`COUNT(RecordId)`) per pivot so all you do is combine into one result set with a UNION ALL with a suitable extra column to identify each pivot.

Otherwise, you have no way to distinguish the 2 different aggregates in the pivot

Comment: I like to use Common Table Expressions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution Tom, that answers my pivot question.

Too bad for me I had the wrong question.  For my problem I'm now feeling it would be better to use a plain grouping query like this instead:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN IsSpecial = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS TotalSpecial,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN IsExpensive = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS TotalExpensive
FROM Records
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate);
```

Then all that is left to do is rotate the results before they are presented.  Nice to know eh?